# Got java.lang.RuntimeException ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException after first startup of app after install from GooglePlay

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

After i migrate to androidX, started to get RuntimeException. Followed instructions from here  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate
and here
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate 
Migrate an existing project
After i build .apk (for release) and install it locally everything is just fine. BUT after i uploaded .apk to Google Play and download/install it from GP on first startup of app i got this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3785)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)

 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2082)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)

 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7529)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)

 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)

 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3780)
```

Close app start it again and everything works as it should ... I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution why this happens. I am not able to reproduce that locally, only after i download from GP. 
This is my build.gradle(Module: app), only important part

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx not important xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    //recycleview library
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    //cardview library
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //circle indicator
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
```

this is my manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

        <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

rest part of manifest are list of activities only.

I just don't get it why this happens only on first lunch of app, every next lunch is just fine. Some advice ??

Comment: Anyone ?? Some suggestion ? :( i still can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations along with your code, so that future users can follow your ideas/code more easily. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23348481)

Comment: May you please explain me why should i use 17.2.1 instead of 18.0.0 version of play-services-ads ? I am migrating a project to androidX i should use latest versions

Comment: @RobotAndroid so if I understood correctly, all i have to do is to implement this package 
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.0.0'
and app will not crash after install it from store and play it for the first time ?

Comment: Yes ```implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0'```